# Bootstrap 3: Rows different length

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I set up my rows and columns like below, the row widths are slightly different.  Suggestions?

EDIT:  The row widths are not different.  The column width does not fill the space.  The fiddle has also been update to illustrate the problem.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background: red;">
      <div class="col-xs-4" id="logo">
          content
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
      </div>
  </div>      
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-push-3">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-pull-7">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2" style="background: #000">
          content
      </div>
  </div>
```

link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PRP89/4/

Comment: I am not sure I see the problem. Everything looks correct to me: http://jsfiddle.net/designingsean/PRP89/5/

Comment: Do you mean the container doesn't take up the entire width?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why Sean's fiddle doesn't show the same issue as mine.  The right most column leaves a 1-2 px line on the right.  It's width does not totally fill the parent container (the row in this case).  It looks like my old computer at work doesn't show the issue either.  It's my new MacBook Pro that I noticed the issue with.